# yum update entire release but limit to a prior version

Tags: centos, centos6, centos6.2

We need to update `yum update` but we want to stay one release back.  For example, we have CentOS 6.2 and want to move to 6.3.  By default, it looks like `yum update` will install 6.4.

On RedHat, this may be done with the `subscription-manager`.  However, because the `subscription-manger` is [not available on CentOS](https://serverfault.com/questions/506148/is-subscription-manager-available-for-centos), this can not be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go into /etc/yum.repos.d/, and carefully look at all of the files in there.

For each file that points to a CentOS repository, disable it by setting `enabled=0`, and make a copy that points to the CentOS 6.3 repo directories on vault.centos.org. Any directory with a "repodata" subdirectory is usable as a yum repository directory.

You'll probably at least want:

```
[centos63]
name=CentOS 6.3 - $basearch
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.3/os/$basearch
enabled=1
cost=1000

[centos63-updates]
name=CentOS 6.3 Updates - $basearch
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.3/updates/$basearch
enabled=1
cost=1000
```

Note that you won't get any security updates that came out since CentOS 6.4 was released. If you install the `yum-plugin-security` module, you may be able to use commands like `yum --enablerepo=centos --security update-minimal` to pull in just the security updates, but I have not checked that, and have not even verified the yum repository names.

Answer (score 2):

Are using spacewalk server do update you Cent OS or are you pulling from Cent OS (Internet).

If you have local spacewalk server using following command you can create channel Cent OS 6.3.

```
#spacewalk-create-channel --user=admin --server=localhost --version=6 --update=3 --release=Server --arch=x86_64 --destChannel=6-CentOS6
```

Once you finish above step then you can add your all Cent OS server which you want keep 6.3.

[Spacewalk](http://people.redhat.com/tcameron/Summit11/rhn/cameron_spurgeon_t_310_rhn_tips_tricks_pt1.pdf)

[Spacewalk -2](http://people.redhat.com/tcameron/Summit11/rhn/cameron_spurgeon_t_420_rhn_tips_tricks_pt2.pdf)

Comment: It is pulling from the Internet..