# Is subscription-manager available for CentOS?

Tags: centos, centos6

I'm trying to fix my updater to [point to a specific release](https://serverfault.com/questions/484841/update-red-hat-enterprise-linuxs-packages-only-to-specific-point-release).  Is the `subscription-manager` for RedHat only?  I don't see it in my CentOS 6.3 (yum) repository.

Comment: What version are you trying to stay on?

Comment: I would like to remain 1 version back on 6.3... I think I have the solution (see this [http://serverfault.com/questions/497646/yum-update-entire-release-but-limit-to-a-prior-version](question)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `subscription-manager` tool is Red Hat-specific, allowing you to manage Red Hat subscriptions. Since CentOS doesn't *have* subscriptions, CentOS 6 omitted this tool.

CentOS 7 now includes `subscription-manager`, which you can use with Red Hat Satellite or its open source versions Spacewalk or Foreman/Katello.

Comment: If you use Katello and mirror CentOS repos, you can treat `CentOS` just as you would treat `RHEL` with subscriptions, products, activation keys, errata and so on.

Comment: subscription manager is required for use with Katello (Satellite 6)

Answer (score 9):

subscription-manager for CentOS 6 is available

```
wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/epel-rhsm.repo http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/candlepin/subscription-manager/epel-subscription-manager.repo
yum install subscription-manager -y
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is available.

If you have an environment with Red Hat Satellite or Foreman ( the Opensource version of satellite 6) it is very useful.

You will be able to see your client systems and all the details (like dmidecode) on the satellite or Foreman.

See the below link on how to install subscription-manager in CentOS 6/7 or Fedora

http://www.candlepinproject.org/docs/subscription-manager/installation.html